# How to set Max Attempts For Queued Notifications in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

In laravel queue system when working with jobs I can set [max tries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout) for each job with adding a public field $tries = n in job class itself
is it possible and How to do the same thing in notification implementing shouldQueue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible in Laravel 5.7.14: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26493

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TestNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $tries = 3; // Max tries

    public $timeout = 15; // Timeout seconds
 }
```